# VueJS - Http Requests - Parent or Child component?

Tags: vue.js

I have the choice to make http request from a parent or a child component.
What are the best practices? axios/ajax request from parent and pass result to children components, or directly from children components?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Add code for things that you've tried and edit your post to include specific questions for the best results.

Comment: If you'll have multiple instances of the child component and all need the same data, detach getting the data from the child into a service, get the data once and make it available cross-app using a simple (or more complex) state management mechanism (simple would mean [an object](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch), and more complex would mean [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)). If you don't need the returned data in the parent, there's no point in the parent knowing about the data at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in my opinion I think the best you can do is build children components as simple as posible for reusability, I mean, imagine that you have a component named "Newsfeed" that show a lot of random stuff, you can use it in a main page for a social media website and for the profile page from someone like Facebook does, the only difference will be at the moment of fetch the data, they will not be the same but the component does, if you explicity make the component fetch the data it will not be reusable

I'm not a Senior or something like that but in my short experience I can say that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Axios still makes use of Ajax.

More so, it depends on where and how the content being fetched would be needed.

If the content is going to be needed by other components in the same parent component or would be used by the parent component itself, then make your query in your parent component.

Else, your child component should handle its own queries and processes.

In simple terms, many things come into consideration when making such decisions. a more detailed explanation could help me figure out a better suggestion.